# self.navigationController is not working from subviews

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a class(parent class) that has three subclasses(class a, class b, class c). I can able to switch between the screens and can see the respective screens for the tabs I choose. Now I would like to navigate to other screen if I click the tableviewcell from class a(where it says Dinesh Ramalingam). so I need to switch over from parent class to parentTwo class if i click the tableviewcell.

This usual method for navigation doesnt work if I am in subviews.

```
settings *set=[[settings alloc]initWithNibName:@"settings" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:set animated:NO];

[set release];
```

[image: Sub class]

Comment: Is settings a subclass of UIViewController ?

Comment: @Ali3n yes settings class is a subclass or UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your Navigation controller and synthesize it in appDelegate.h and .m file..And then check out did you add delegate to it..If u didn't add delegate to ur navigation Controller then it will not recognize your following command..

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:set animated:NO];
```

Answer (score -2):

please remove this [set release]; and take your class object in .h file so it can be works

thanks

Comment: He does not need to put it in the header file (waste of memory) and since he isn't, release should go there.